# Summarise and create a stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

For a population of individuals I have a regular time series of what category they fall into. I would like to summarise the composition of this population over time, by the categories, as a stacked bar chart in R. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
id <- seq(1:25)
t1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE)
t2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6))
t3 <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4))

df <- data.frame(cbind(id, t1, t2, t3))
```

with frequencies:

```
> table(df$t1)

A B C D E 
7 6 3 2 7 
> table(df$t2)

 B  C  D  E 
 3  4  5 13 
> table(df$t3)

 A  B  C  D  E 
 4  2  5  4 10
```

So, at time period 1, 7 of the 25 are category A, 6 category B, whilst at time period 2, none are category A, 3 category B, etc. The chart will look like this (from EXCEL):

[image: mock up of required plot]

Can this be made in ggplot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

melt(setDT(df), id.var = "id")[, .N, .(variable, value)][, perc := N / sum(N), variable] %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = perc, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. I should have said that in reality I have nearly 350,000 rows. This solution appears to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by first reshaping into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then get the frequency `count` and use the summarised 'n' as 'y' in `ggplot` `aes` while specifying the 'x' as 'name' and the `fill` as 'value' column created from `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
    count(name, value) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = n, fill = value)) +
        geom_col()
```

---

If we need proportion instead of count,

```
df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
      count(name, value) %>%
      group_by(name) %>%
      mutate(prop =  n/sum(n)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = name, y = prop, fill = value)) + 
         geom_col() +
         scale_y_continuous(labels= scales::percent)
```